# How to slide down an image in a hovered text

Tags: html, css, hover, dropdown, slide

I'm trying to create a "bubble" (with additional info, in this case-- a picture) slide down when you hover over a symbol in the text, and then slide back up when you move the mouse away.

I've looked through solutions to similar problems, but none of them quite do the trick. I should probably preface all this by noting I'm a self-taught "programmer" (can't quite call myself that, as it's mainly a hobby and I use codes for school-related projects). That being said, I have a super basic understanding of html and css, and would typically use them to do the job. I tried setting the image's bottom to a negative value, and then setting up the hover as 0 (and adding transition), but that didn't work.

Hope it's okay to post a link to w3schools where I'd typically try out the code before posting it on the webpage - that way you could see how the images are currently just popping up.
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G6Q7NNO1WJ4G

I'm not even sure if this type of "animation" is possible without using a different coding language. Also, another issue I'm experiencing currently is the images tend to float to the left, even if they're in the middle of the text, and if there's a way to fix that too (so that they just slide down below the triangular symbol), that'd be great.

Hopefully there's someone that could give me some advice... Thank you!

Comment: I'll do my best! I've dabbled in javascript before, but could never quite get the hang of it. But if you say it'd be much easier and simpler, I am willing to try it once again. What do I need to do?

Comment: @Tuneer I disagree, for simpler animations like this, css is enough to handle things.

Comment: @Achtung I'll take your word on it then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you use two elements with id hover. Ids are unique and it's best if you use a class instead.

If you wish for things to have nicer transitions there is a [css property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) for that.

In this case, you could hide hover `img` with `max-height: 0`; instead of `display: none` and then make max-height into a transition. I made an [example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wVyvEK)  on Codepen (I would suggest Codepen over w3schools).

**HTML**

```
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <span class="hover"><img src="https://placehold.it/200x200"></span>, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vel eleifend eros. Morbi varius aliquam ante, sit amet iaculis augue euismod quis. Sed placerat varius diam, et facilisis turpis aliquam quis. Quisque mollis nunc at purus fermentum, eget pulvinar nulla iaculis. Sed mollis at nunc faucibus ultricies. Integer sit amet luctus leo. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Maecenas suscipit quam sed enim imperdiet sollicitudin. Proin nec diam condimentum <span class="hover"><img src="https://placehold.it/200x200"></span>, molestie diam sed, ullamcorper eros. Mauris lobortis massa ac felis consectetur dictum a ac elit. Sed sodales purus vel sapien fringilla dictum.
```

**CSS**

```
    .hover:before {content:"▼"; display:inline-block; position:relative;}
    .hover img{
      max-height: 0;
      position:absolute;
      transition: max-height linear .2s;
    }
    .hover:hover img{
        max-height: 300px;
    }
```

Comment: This works just fine, and it might even look nicer that way, then the slide down/up effect I was trying to achieve. Thank you @Achtung I really appreciate you helping out with this!